# How to block a Facebook page?

Tags: spam-prevention, facebook

My feed is covered with "9gag content", and is there a way for me not to see it? I of course haven't liked the page, but my friends constantly like and share "their content", so it always ends up infront of my eyes.

What I have done so far:

- Reported the 9gag page as spam
- Reported everything I see from 9gag as spam

**Is there a way to tell Facebook I just don't want to see anything from both 9gag.com and 9gag's Facebook page?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Chrome (or Chromium, probably), you can use [Facebook Filter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pinhinoocjdghpnkadfchkggmipcngoa) to block content by keyword. I haven't come upon an equivalent tool for Firefox, though. If you're up for tinkering, of course, you could make your own. ;)

Comment: I am in the process of making one, actually, but I'm only using it to blog Facebook's own annoying UI parts (mainly nav divs).

Comment: The extension suggested in this answer is no longer being maintained and no longer works. See my answer below for a working and up to date Facebook filtering extension

Answer (score 1):

if the post actually contains the words "9gag.com" anywhere in it, you can filter it out using a browser extension such as "FB Purity" : http://fbpurity.com which is compatible with Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera. You just need to put the text "9gag.com" into the extension's Custom Text filter.

Of course if the "9gag" text only appears in the image, its not going to be able to filter it, as it would require some form of "optical character recognition" which isnt easily doable in a browser extension. Though the above mentioned extension also has a "hide shared photos" filter, and that should block a lot of the 9gag and other joke and meme photos from the news feed.